# sending special characters to webservices problem iphone

Tags: iphone, json, special-characters

My problem is with the special characters, i am trying to send one JSON string to services, in that string i am sending one string with special characters like **"!@#$%^&*()_+!@#$%^&())^%%"** but i am not getting the response from the server.

can any one help me on this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to encode your string ?
I think this url will help you : [encoding an NSString on iOS](http://madebymany.com/blog/url-encoding-an-nsstring-on-ios)